# Trying to load a ML model in Django in order to classify user submitted images

Tags: python, django, tensorflow

I have made a small image classifier that I want to use in my website. I have it working locally. My view is something a long the lines of

```
from .predict import classify

def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyImageClass(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            context = classify(cd)
            return render(request, 'my_html.html', context)
    ...
```

Where the problem is in `predict.py`, I have

```
def classify(cd):
    loaded_model = tf.keras.model.load_model(filepath=r'C:\Django 
                                             Projects\my_project\my_app\trained_model')
    ...
    return context
```

As I said, the above works, but I would like to be able to load the model with a relative file path instead. I have tried both saving as a SavedModel and as an h5 file as done [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load). When I run `tf.keras.model.load_model('my_model.h5')` (say in main.py) in python, I have no problem with the file being in the same directory as the file main.py, but if I have the same code as part of `predict.classify`, I get `OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at my_model.h5/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}` while using my website via `py manage.py runserver`. I'm guessing the issue might have to do with static files? I'm not too sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The tip on [this page](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/NoSuchFileOrDirectory/) seems to be a work  around. It's working for me, but I would be interested to hear thoughts from other people.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are quite far from the right solution:

- First of all, I recommend that you leave FVB and switch to CBV. (this is essential in django, believe me)
- Second, if you are going to use "h5" or "hdf5" with "json", you must create correctly the session and global graphs, this way every time you make runserver and send a call to the API only the prediction will be generated and you will not have to load the model in every call.
- Thirdly, if you use Django in production with Gunicorn+Nginx, you can get much more out of it by converting the "h5" model to "tflite" and generating the prediction using interpreters, thus avoiding data crosses in parallel calls, since that's difficult to configure in graphs/sessions (but you can, I did it), and also, it reduces considerably the final response time, the RAM consumption and the amount of code you must write for the api to work well, as well as the total weight of the project since tflite is lighter.
- As an extra, tflite not only works with gunicorn+nginx, it also works quite well at localhost level. (debug true)

Here a example project
(Fashion Mnist added)
[Django + Tensorflow Lite](https://github.com/Nouvellie/django-js-ml/tree/main/project/apps/tensorflow)